# cannot replace [''] with method pad on a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

running python2.7

Question1

I want to replace empty string '' with None in my dataframe "test":

```
    from numpy.random import randn
    test = pd.DataFrame(randn(3,2))
    test.iloc[0,0]=''
    test.replace('', None)
```

Give me error TypeError:

cannot replace [''] with method pad on a DataFrame.

What went wrong?

Question 2:

from numpy.random import randn

```
test = pd.DataFrame(randn(3,2))
# this works
test.iloc[0,1]= 'A'
test[1] = test[1].replace('A','b')
# this does not
test.iloc[0,0]=''
test.loc[0] = test[0].replace('', None)


test 
          0         1
0                   b
1  0.042052  -1.44156
2  0.462131 -0.303288
```

I am expecting

```
test 
          0         1
0    None           b
1  0.042052  -1.44156
2  0.462131 -0.303288
```

Comment: I don't get any error.  What version of pandas and python?

Answer (score 6):

None is being interpreted as a lack of an argument.  Try:

```
test.replace({'':None})
```

Question 2:

```
test.where(test != '', None)
```

Comment: running on python 2.7. your suggestion gives error: TypeError: cannot replace [set(['', None])] with method pad on a DataFrame

Comment: @Lisa what version of pandas?  I'm on 20.3 and I don't get that error running this line:  `pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, ''], 'col2': [3, 4]}).replace({'':None})`

Comment: This doesn't work on pandas 0.23.0 with the OP's code because she doesn't assign the result.

Answer (score 1):

Just use not-a-number. Pandas would convert your `None` into not-a-number anyways*. Second, do not forget to assign your result to a new variable or set the `inplace` paramater to `True` instead. `test.replace('', np.NaN)` does nothing on its own.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import randn
test = pd.DataFrame(randn(3,2))
test.iloc[0,0]=''
test = test.replace('', np.NaN)
```

*Pandas works best and is most efficient when all the data has the same datatype. That's numpy.float64 in your case. `np.NaN` is also a numpy float. If you wanted to have `None` in your dataframe, everything would need to be stored as `object` datatype which is less efficient. `np.NaN` is probably what you need.